# SET more than 1 row output into 1 variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, sql-server-2016

I am wanting to be able to save more than just 1 output from a SELECT query in a single variable.

Currently I am gathering my needed data like so:

```
DECLARE @something1 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @something2 VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @something3 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @something1 = (
  SELECT 
     Custom AS 'XXL Format' 
  FROM 
     tblData 
  WHERE 
     ID = 1);

SET @something2 = (
  SELECT 
     Custom.value('(/Individual/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Non XML Format' 
  FROM 
     tblData 
  WHERE 
     ID = 1)

SET @something3 = (
  SELECT 
     tbl1.paper, 
     tbl2.type 
  FROM 
     tblData AS tbl1 
  JOIN tblData2 tbl2 
     ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID 
  WHERE 
     ID = 1);
```

I have the following demo that shows what I am wanting to do

```
DECLARE @tester VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tester = (
  SELECT 
     tbl1.Custom AS 'XXL Format',
     tbl1.Custom.value('(/Individual/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Non XML Format'
     tbl1.paper, 
     tbl2.type 
  FROM 
     tblData AS tbl1 
  JOIN tblData2 tbl2 
     ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID 
  WHERE 
     ID = 1);
```

I get the error of:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when
> the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Both demos can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff6b8/21260)

I have tried to set the variable to "table" and store the data like that but that also does not seem to work correctly [I'm sure I am doing something wrong - that may be the answer to this question I'm asking]

How can I just use 1 variable for all that the above query outputs?

Comment: If your expectation is a single value with concatenated strings, consider the `STRING_AGG` function.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess I was correct with the set the variable to a temp "table". I finally just now got it to work for my needs!

```
DECLARE @tmpTbl table (_xml, _parsedXML, _paper, _type)

INSERT INTO @tmpTbl 
  SELECT 
     tbl1.Custom AS 'XML Format',
     tbl1.Custom.value('(/Individual/text())[1]', 'varchar(MAX)') AS 'Non XML Format',
     tbl1.paper, 
     tbl2.type  
  FROM 
     tblData AS tbl1 
  JOIN tblData2 AS tbl2 
     ON tbl1.ID = tbl2.ID 
  WHERE 
     ID = 1;

DECLARE @something1 VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT _xml FROM @tmpTbl);
DECLARE @something2 VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT _parsedXML FROM @tmpTbl);
DECLARE @something3 VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT _paper FROM @tmpTbl);
DECLARE @something4 VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT _type FROM @tmpTbl);

DELETE FROM @tmpTbl --Not really needed but nice to be offical :)
```

This above stores the values into one place. Although its not inside 1 variable I guess having to create a temp table isn't all that bad for the database/performance...

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that the subquery returned more than one value.  You can use `top` if you don't care which value gets assigned:

```
SET @tester = (SELECT TOP (1) description FROM ForgeRock);
```

Comment: Well I want all the rows it outputs and place them into that 1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return only one value you can try `top` or `limit` like `SET @tester = (SELECT TOP 1 description FROM ForgeRock);` or `SET @tester = (SELECT description FROM ForgeRock LIMIT 1);`